# Safari can load internet but none of the other apps cannot!

Tags: mac, safari, internet

This is by far the weirdest problem I've come across, 
My mac can perfectly access internet through safari web browser, but when I tried to do

```
ping www.google.com
```

through the terminal, it's requests is being timed out.

None of the other apps are able to reach internet either. Dropbox, Skype, Spotify all showing offline, except the browser itself

I'm guessing something bad with the DNS, but spend 2 hours trying to fix this with no luck

Comment: What if you ping an IP address directly? Like `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: If DNS was wonky, nothing would work. What DNS servers are configured? Try changing to Google's servers: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. In addition, reboot the router the Mac connects to. If this is a laptop, does the problem persist when you use other networks? If you have the built-in firewall running, disable it. If Parental Controlls is active on your account, disable that as well. Lastly, create a temporary user account and see if the problem occurs only for you, or for all users.

Comment: I've tried adding googles DNS and still no luck, and there's other devices connected to the same network and they just work fine. There's no firewall running on the system.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that safari cannot resolve new qualified domain names, I'm guessing its resolving from the cache, so I'm certain that this is a dns issue

Comment: and `ping 8.8.8.8` results in timeout as well

Answer (score 1):

Since DNS resolves but the ping responses time out, we can rule out a DNS issue.

Things to try to diagnose the source of the problem:

- It's possible that IPv6 is working but IPv4 is not.  Try `ping6 ipv6.google.com` to see if this is the case.
- Find out whether a proxy has been configured that Safari might be using. Go to System Preferences, and search for *Proxies* to jump right to the tab in the Network config (also accessible from Safari preferences > Advanced > Proxies).
- Confirm that other devices on the network don't have this same issue. It's possible that a transparent network proxy is filtering traffic.
- Restart the computer, because this is a pretty unusual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open up any other website if it's working or not maybe your Google website is just pulling up from the  cache fileson your Mac and if it's not opening that means they some problem to go DNS all router or it could be a problem if your whole Internet connection that going to be a ston on your Mac and if it's not opening that means they some problem to go DNS all router or it could be a problem if your whole Internet connection that Its down. Try using any other devices after this and if you have the same problem then you should call your service provider and they would be able to help you out